# Inno Setup - #define directive -How to emit a pre-processor variable by string?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm sorry about title if it's wrong. I'll explain what my requirement.

I need to set class id `*_CLSID`  based on `AppName` in Script.values dynamically. (Here `"{{5c587137-edfd-4b32-952a-62bf5d10bg23}}"`)

**Sample.iss**

```
;This can be modified by User who Build installer
#define MyAppName "App1"

;This is my two Applications Class id's
#define App1_CLSID "{{5c587137-edfd-4b32-952a-62bf5d10bg23}}"
#define App2_CLSID "{{8c583137-4dfd-4b42-962a-6234fd10bg23}}"

;CLSID name set dynamically with help of MyAppName
#define CLSID MyAppName+"_CLSID"

[Registry]
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "Application\CLSID"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData:{#{#CLSID}}; Flags: uninsdeletekey
```

I tried `ValueData:{#{#CLSID}}` for setting CLASS Id like 
 `ValueData:{{5c587137-edfd-4b32-952a-62bf5d10bg23}}`

But throws an error `[ISPP] Expression expected but opening brace ("{") found.`

Here `{#CLSID}` means `"App1_CLSID"`.So i think  `{#{#CLSID}}` and `{#App1_CLSID}` are same.

How can resolve this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Just `ValueData: {#CLSID}`.

Comment: Thanks for Reply @TLama. But  {#CLSID} returns `App1_CLSID`. It's a string. But i need value of  `App1_CLSID`

Comment: Ah, I see. Now I think I got your question... You want to emit to the `CLSID` variable either `App1_CLSID` or `App2_CLSID` depending on the  `MyAppName` value (used as a prefix). Though I don't believe that this will be possible. You are trying to make an identifier from a value.

Comment: @TLama, Yes. I found similar query at http://news.jrsoftware.org/news/innosetup/msg54260.html. But it's suitable for me. Please look at once